# Passing an array from a method in file 1 to a method in file 2 without using a extra parameter in a method

Tags: c, arrays, pass-by-reference, memcpy

I am getting all Zeroes in global_array_of_file2.Idea is to get the updated values from file1.c

```
        ========================file1.c===========================  
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int global_array_of_file1[10];


    void func1(int a1,int b)
    {
      int array1_of_func1[10] = {0};
      int a;
       array1_of_func1[5] = 23;
       array1_of_func1[6] = 34;

    memcpy(global_array_of_file1,array1_of_func1,10*sizeof(int));
     for (a = 0; a < 9; a++)
     {
       printf("from func_1 : global_array = %d \n " , global_array_of_file1[a]);

     }
    }

    void init_pointer(int *tmp)
    {

      tmp = global_array_of_file1;

    }
    ~  


        ==========================file2.c======================
#include<stdio.h>
#include "file1.h"
int global_array_of_file2[10] = {0};
int main()
{
  int i;
  init_pointer(global_array_of_file2);

  func1(3,4);

  for(i = 0; i < 9 ; i++)
  {

  printf("global_array_of_file2 = %d \n" , global_array_of_file2[i]);
  }


return 0;


}

        ========================file1.h===========================  

            void init_pointer(int *tmp);
            void func1(int a,int b);
```

Comment: Nowhere in the code you have given us is there any point at which you update (or even reference) `global_array_of_file2`, except the call to: `init_global_array_of_file_2(global_array_of_file2)` … and you haven't shown us the code for that function. So where do you expect the update to happen?

Comment: its inside :   // keep calling func1() at regular interval and get the updated values of array1_of_func1 which i am tried to update by passing a pointer in file1.c and then updating that pointer. updated the func2() body

Comment: why is your size one time 10 and the other time 5?

Comment: I repeat my previous point! Show some code us where you ***think*** `global_array_of_file2` is being updated - or we can't really help.

Comment: Functions need return types. It's weird that you've neglected to include return types even though you're talking about calling `func1()` to get data.

Comment: Is it too much to ask you to show your *actual* code? What you've got above isn't it because that would never compile. Let's see an example that actually compiles so we can talk about it in concrete terms.

Comment: give me some time, I will paste soon . I have to remove some legacy code.

Comment: updated the compilable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think this can be fixed easily by doing the below :

declare extern int global_array_of_file1[10] in file1.c

define int global_array_of_file1[10] = {0}; in file2.c

I then dont even need to initialize the pointer from file2.c ( no need to call init_pointer) and extra RAM too will be saved :) !

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

First issue is:

the code for init_pointer does nothing:

```
void init_pointer(int *tmp)
{
  tmp = global_array_of_file1;
}
```

as tmp variable is a copy of the input variable (called by value), it does nothing.
To have it work correctly it should be something like this:

```
void init_pointer(int **tmp)
{
  *tmp = global_array_of_file1;
}
```

However, as the global_array_of_file2 is declared as array, it is actually a static pointer which cannot be changed, so you cannot modify its value using statement like **tmp= global_array_of_file1.

Therefor to make it work, you should call memcpy within the init pointer method:
like this:

```
void init_pointer(int *tmp)
{
    memcpy( tmp, global_array_of_file1, 10 * sizeof(int) );
}
```

The second issue, is that the code at main, first call the init_pointer (which does nothing), then it calls 'func1' which initialize the array. the order shall be the opposite. first call func1 to set the array with the appropriate values, then call the init_array method to copy this information to global array 2.
so instead of

```
  init_pointer(global_array_of_file2);
  func1(3,4);
```

it shall be

```
  func1(3,4);
  init_pointer(global_array_of_file2);
```

This is all if you want to have a **copy** of the global_array_file1 at file2.

If you want, you can have the **same array shared between files**, to do so:

at file1.h declare the array as extern:

```
 extern int global_array_of_file1[10];
```

Then you can simply use it at file2.c which include file1.h

Comment: Yeah, extern approach i liked most !

Answer (score -1):

The memcpy is wrong. You just copy 10 bytes.

An int is usually 4 Bytes long (32 bit), thus you only copy parts of the array, namely the first ten bytes, thus you copy just the ints with index 0,1,2 and half of 4.

You need to copy 10 * sizeof(int)

Comment: Yes, because that code is not a working program. But that memcopy does not what he thinks it does, thus I pointed it out.